# Is there an expression that describes looking for something that probably isn't there, or looking in unlikely places for a solution

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-requests, humor

I am looking for an idiom or phrase that describes, in a humorous or funny way, the act of looking for something that probably isnt't there, or the act of looking for a solution in a place where it is not likely to be found.

Comment: something like *look in vain* ?

Comment: While this question is closely related to the one it's been marked a duplicate of, I don't believe it strictly is. This question is *specifically* related to a humorous expression, not simply a general expression. I've voted to reopen it, but I would have honestly done so even if I hadn't provided my own answer. I actually upvoted both *snipe hunt* and *fool's errand* too.

Answer (score 1):

A fruitless search (looking for something that isn't or probably isn't there) described *humorously* is a **wild goose chase**.

From [The Idioms](https://www.theidioms.com/wild-goose-chase/):

> - wasting resource working on something that does not exist
> - spending time searching for something that is simply impossible to find
> - a foolish search for something that cannot be achieved
> - a chase for something that's beyond your reach
>
> The convict escaped the police custody on the way to jail. Police is apparently on a **wild goose chase** after he vanished into woods.
>
> It turns out that my brother took my car keys. I had been on a **wild goose chase** this whole morning searching them in the entire house.

Answer (score 1):

How about **fool's errand**? From Cambridge:

> **[fool's errand](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fool-s-errand?q=fool%27s%20errand)**: an effort that is unlikely to be successful

From Google:

> **[fool's errand](https://www.bing.com/search?q=fool%27s%20errand&form=EDGEAR&qs=PF&cvid=5919d59e737e490da4e8afacc0a6b87e&cc=US&setlang=en-US&plvar=0&PC=DCTS)**: a task or activity that has no hope of success

The act of looking for something that probably isn't there, or the act of looking for a solution in a place where it is not likely to be found, is a **fool's errand.** And fool's engaged in tomfoolery are certainly humorous. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Snipe hunt**

> 1. A practical joke in which the victim is sent on a hunt for a fictitious animal called a snipe.
>      When I was in the Cub Scouts, the youngest members were always sent out on a snipe hunt by the counselors on the night of our first big campout.
> 2. By extension, any hunt, search, or quest for something that is fictitious, non-existent, elusive, or illusory.
>      The president has pledged to make universal healthcare a reality, but I think he's really just on a snipe hunt.

snipe hunt. (n.d.) Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. (2015). Retrieved May 6 2020 from https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snipe+hunt

Comment: Good answer, but the second example seems like a strange use of "snipe hunt" - a big aspect of the snipe hunt is that the hunter *does not know* that what they're looking for doesn't exist. Planning to make something a reality, when that thing is already known to not exist, doesn't sound like a snipe hunt to me. Universal health care actually does exist in certain countries, so this isn't a case of searching for something nonexistent. Something like "Scientists search for cold fusion" might be a better example of a snipe hunt, since we don't know if that's possible or not.